# Can I add my App icon to default Photo library in IOS?

Tags: ios, photo-gallery

I want to add my App icon to default Photo library but I do not know how to do that? Can it be done?
You can see the photo at [here](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/594/q2c9.png)

I want to add my app icon for user after select video or photo, can click on my app icon to open my app.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add your app in the iOS "Photos" app. But it's possible if you want other (3rd party) apps to be able to open files in yours.

A good place to start is [this Instagram documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/#) on how they do it, and from that link you can see that the relevant Apple information lies in the `UIDocumentInteractionController` class reference and [Document Interaction Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010409-SW1).

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. I want to add my app icon for user can open my app after choose video or photo. How can do that?